# How do you use the result of a graphql query as a return value in a react functional component?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-hooks

I'm new to react, and I'm querying the GRAPHQL endpoint and sending it a json object. I have a file called Service.jsx with a functional component which contains the query and returns a promise. That function gets rendered in List.jsx where I want to return the value of 'id' we get from my query. What do I need to put in the return block to get the id? Thanks

I've tried incident.count to get the number of items but can't get the values

list.jsx

```
     import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import IncidentService from "services/Service.jsx";



const App = () => {

    const [incidents, setIncidents] = useState([]);


    useEffect(() => {
        var incidentService = IncidentService();
        incidentService.getIncidents()
            .then(result => {
                console.log(result.data.incidentsTop20);
                setIncidents(result.data.incidentsTop20);
            })
    }, [true])

    return <>
        <h1>Count: {incidents.count}</h1>
        /* code to return id should go here */
    </>
}

export default App;
```

service.jsx

```
import React from 'react'


const IncidentService = () => {
    var getIncidents = async () => {

        const query = {
            "query": `
              {
                incidentsTop20 {
                  id

              }
            }`
        }

        const url = "https://localhost:44344/graphql";

        const opts = {
            method: "POST",
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            body: JSON.stringify(query)
        };

        var result = await fetch(url, opts)

        var data = await result.json()

        return data;
    }


    return {
        getIncidents: getIncidents
    }
}

export default IncidentService;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What do I need to put in the return block to get the id?

Given `incidents` is a list of `incident`s, just use `map()` to iterate per incident.id.

```
const getTimes = (incident) => (incident.map(i => (<span>i.time</span>)))

return (
  <>
    <h1>Count: {incidents.length}</h1>
    {incidents.map(incident => (
      <span>{incident.id}</span>
      {getTimes(incident.incident)}
    )}
  </>
)
```

Comment: Thank you! Just a note, It would need to be {id.id}, what if the structure was nested in the schema? "query": `
              {
                incidentsTop20 {
                  id
                incidents{ time
              }} How could I access those values? id.time does not work, how can I iterate through each value for time for every id? Thanks again

Comment: @kbearski `incident.incident.map(i => i.time)`

Comment: I don't understand, do I need a nested span tag? How can I return each time for each id?

Comment: Your suggestion was good. I found that you could also use  <tbody> {                
                   incidents.map(i =>                        
                        <tr key={i.id}>
                            
                            <td>{i.time}</td> </tr>)} </tbody>